# Why can't I call a class method with its object?

Tags: java, user-interface, keylistener, swingx

Gym.java

```
public class Gym extends ActiveObject { 
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

GymController.java

```
public class GymController extends WindowController implements KeyListener{

    private Gym gym;

    public void begin() {
        Gym gym = new gym(canvas, new Location(dx, dy), delay, this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            gym.run();
        }
    }
}
```

There is an object and its moving code in Gym.java file... and I wanted to call that to GymController.java file's keyPressed method... so that the object moves when the user presses the space bar. 
How do I even link these two files in the first place...? 
But the compiler is giving me an error saying that it cannot find symbol.
How can I call a method from another .java file into current file's keyPressed method properly, so that it compiles...?

Comment: The instance variable `gym` is NOT initialized. You are creating a new `Gym` object in the begin method. Remove the class name before `gym` in the `begin()` method. It should be `gym = new Gym(...)` and not `Gym gym = new Gym(...)`.

Comment: first of all: `new Gym` instead of `new gym`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by comments, your problem lies in:

```
public void begin() {
  Gym gym = new gym(canvas, new Location(dx, dy), delay, this);
}
```

And it should be:

```
public void begin() {
  gym = new Gym(canvas, new Location(dx, dy), delay, this);
}
```

First of all, new takes the class name, you are building an actual object from a "pattern". Then, doing `Gym gym =...` creates a local variable within the scope of your begin() method. It will be discarded on return from begin.
If you just use `gym` or `this.gym`, it will assign the new instance to the member variable.

But be careful, your initial gym instance will create a new gymcontroller instance which will, in turn create a new gym instance. So the gym.run() will not use the same instance of gym than the one who created it. If that was your intention, you need to pass the `this` reference from gym to gymcontroller.